# Will another full backup in mirroring disturb the mirroring

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have to restore one database 'XYZ' onto another standalone SQL server.

'XYZ' database is the part of mirroring on principal server. I want to know if I take another FULL backup just prior to restore, will it affect the mirroring or mirroring will get disturbed. What should be the proper steps to do this activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can I do database backups for a mirrored database?

> Yes, it is allowed to do database backups in the Principal database.
>   However, it is not allowed on the Mirror server since which is in the
>   Restoring state.

**with some restrictions :** **Restrictions on Backup and Restore During Mirroring**:

While a database mirroring session is active, the following restrictions apply:

- Backup and restore of the mirror database are not allowed.
- Backup of the principal database is allowed, but BACKUP LOG WITH NORECOVERY is not allowed.
- Restoring the principal database is not allowed.

Check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms191235(v=sql.105)) for more information